# r data frame- convert values to text and rank from most to least occurrences per row

Tags: r, dataframe, ranking

New to R and having an issue converting formulas from from excel to R. Any advice would be great.
I have a data frame called allwins_df, where I want to change each value to the first letter of the column name.

Then I need to calculate the number of occurrences of each letter on each date and rank them from highest to lowest number of occurrences. Lastly, if there is a tie the tie-winner is the letter who's underlying number was the greatest. i.e on 1/5/01 one of the B values had a higher value than the A's so B is first, then A, then C. Sample of data frame:

```
Date        A.B  A.C  B.A   B.C  C.A  C.B…
2001-01-01  N/A  NA   0.14  0.35 0.43 NA
2001-01-02  0.8  NA   NA    0.5  NA   0.32
2001-01-03  0.75 0.8  NA    0.65 NA   0.9
2001-01-04  NA   0.66 0.91  NA   NA   NA
2001-01-05  0.52 0.62 0.48  0.82 0.4  NA
```

With some help I used the following code to turn the values into letters but not sure if I can use the resulting output to rank from most to least occurrences and handle ties.

```
 cols <- sub("\\..*", "",names(allwins_df)[-1])
    mat <- which(!is.na(allwins_df[-1]), arr.ind = TRUE)
    allwins_df[-1][mat]<- allwins_df[-1][mat] <- cols[mat[, 2]]
```

Output from code above -only changing values to letters:

```
Date        A.B A.C B.A B.C C.A C.B…
2001-01-01  N/A NA  B   B   C   NA
2001-01-02  A   A   NA  B   NA  C
2001-01-03  A   A   NA  B   NA  C
2001-01-04  NA  A   B   NA  NA  NA
2001-01-05  A   A   B   B   C   NA
```

Final Goal Output Example:

```
Date            
2001-01-01  B   C   
2001-01-02  A   B   C
2001-01-03  A   C   B
2001-01-04  B   A   
2001-01-05  B   A   C
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there a A missing at 2001-01-04?

Comment: And should it be "A C B" for 2001-01-03? Both B and C have 1 but C has a higher value.

Comment: you are correct. It has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible strategy with `tidyverse` libraries `tidyr` and `dplyr`

Using the data

```
dd<-read.table(text="Date        A.B  A.C  B.A   B.C  C.A  C.B
2001-01-01  N/A  NA   0.14  0.35 0.43 NA
2001-01-02  0.8  NA   NA    0.5  NA   0.32
2001-01-03  0.75 0.8  NA    0.65 NA   0.9
2001-01-04  NA   0.66 0.91  NA   NA   NA
2001-01-05  0.52 0.62 0.48  0.82 0.4  NA", header=TRUE, na.strings=c("NA","N/A"))
```

We can do the following

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dd %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Date) %>% 
  separate(name, c("first","second")) %>% 
  group_by(Date, first) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  summarize(count=n(), max=max(value)) %>% 
  arrange(Date, desc(count), desc(max)) %>% 
  mutate(rank=row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(Date, names_from=rank, values_from=first, values_fill=NA)
```

Which returns

```
  Date       `1`   `2`   `3`  
  <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 2001-01-01 B     C     NA   
2 2001-01-02 A     B     C    
3 2001-01-03 A     C     B    
4 2001-01-04 B     A     NA   
5 2001-01-05 B     A     C
```

The idea is that you reshape your data into a more tidy format. Here we turn those columns into rows. Then split the names up so can we look at just the first letter. Then we count them and keep track of the max value for each better. We sort them, and then we reshape them to the wide format that matches your desired shape. Though you might want to rethink that because such a shape isn't always easy to work with in R. "Tidy" data is typically "rectangular" where each row has the same number of columns. Having ragged data like isn't pretty but it all depends on what you are going to do down stream.

Note that in general you want to be careful about trying to directly translate code from excel to R. These two programs work very differently and sometime solving the same problem will involve very different strategy to be efficient in the different environments.

Comment: MrFlick-Thank you for your assistance and insight. I am not sure if the data should be wide or long.  The next step (from my excel spreadsheet) is to apply a series of if than statements to x number (up to 10) of  letters from the final results. In excel I wrote a decision tree with 10+ if statements. I am at a lose how to code them in R.  I don't want to nest them inside each other, I am thinking of writing small functions and using them with ifelse or ???. Thanks for any additional thoughts on this.

Comment: MrFlick- your suggestion worked almost perfectly. Except the code drops any dates where all the variables are NAs. But I need all dates. If a date has only NAs I need to copy the values from the previous date to this date. I tried adding .drop= False to the group_by, but that didn't work. I then tried adding  mutate_all(funs(na.locf(., na.rm = FALSE))) after the group_by, but I then got incorrect values. Any thoughts or assistance would be great.

Comment: @Doug You can probably take out the filter that’s dropping all the NA values but then you’ll need to adjust the summarize() functions to properly account for the NA values in which ever way will give you what you require.

Answer (score 0):

MrFlick solved my issue. I merged a date vector with Mrflick's output and got just what I was looking for.  Now off the the next issue